# Is the server running on host "db" (172.22.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I got my docker compose with postgres and django. Nevertheless when trying to build i am receiving the error below. How can i fix it?

```
Is the server running on host "db" (172.22.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Log containing the error:**

```
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "db" (172.22.0.2) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
web_1  |     self.run()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
web_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
web_1  |     self.check_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
web_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
web_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
web_1  |     self.build_graph()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
web_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     if self.has_table():
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
web_1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
web_1  |     return self._cursor()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 218, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "db" (172.22.0.2) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  |
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   |
db_1   | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   |
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   |
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile st
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**dockerfile**

```sh
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Answer (score 0):

`depends_on` is defining the boot-order in Docker. However, it does not wait for a server to completely spin up. That means the `web` service is probably overtaking the `db` service.

Here is an explanation by Docker itself on it: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

TL;DR: It's normal for distributed systems to need to wait on another service to become available. You can either implement a logic (like retry) in your `web` service or you can use a script like wait-for-it (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to wait for the other service to be available before starting the actual service.

Still TL;DR?

Instructions:

1. Copy wait-for-it.sh to you folder.
2. Change the command (btw: you could also specify what to start in your Dockerfile) to: `./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Could u showne exactly qhere should i putthis want script in my code?

Comment: added instructions to my answer...